# How to replace whole urls in my site?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on PHP site.
How to replace space in url with - or %20?
What function I need to use to decode url?
Do I need to change someting in .htaccess?

Comment: You could look into [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace).

Comment: Ok where to declare in maybe in functions ?

Comment: Show us some code. All we can do is give you links, and guess at what you are trying to do. Code is concrete and easier to respond to.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you can use `urldecode("http://yoursitehere.com")`

The opposite of this function is `urlencode("http://yoursitehere.com")`

It is one of these that you're looking for - I am not sure which as the question is not specific.

Comment: I don't know I'm newbie.I just want to replace %20 with - in url  I think str_replace is for this job.

Comment: @creeds you want to replace a %20 with a space?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a custom URL based on the parameters you're gonna use in a given page you have to create a URL rewrite rule in .htaccess, then send the data to another script which will process this data and redirect the user based on the format you have defined on htaccess. 
Let's suppose you want your dashboard to display the user's name with a dash after the word dashboard.

You should have something like this in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dashboard\-([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ dashboard.php?id=$1
```

In the php script that processes and redirects you should have something like:

```
//Get user's name and sabe it on $userName and user's ID on $userId
header("Location: dashboard-$id-$userName.html"); //redirects to the url
```